# Dynamix regex of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to create a regex for the following string:

```
"SEARCHCONTENT STTYPE_YU KAT_ALL CAMP_ALL STTYPE_LAVERE CAMP_1 KAT_71 KAT_79 KAT_81 "
```

Im creating the regex from a form with checkboxes so the user is able to filter the different values.

Lets say the user have checked 3 checkboxes with the values: `KAT_ALL`, `KAT_71` & `KAT_81`

I then want to check those values against the string. I guess the regex im looking for is kind of like this: `"KAT_ALL+AND/OR+KAT_71+AND/OR+KAT_81"`. How do I write this in JavaScript-regex format?

EDIT:

I got my code working after reading @yarons comment below. Now I have another case: I want to check if the string contains `SSTYPE_YU AND (KAT_71 OR KAT_81)`.

I can't get the following regex to work, any ideas on why? `(?=SSTYPE_YU)(?=KAT_71|KAT_81)`

Comment: what is it, `and` or `or`?

Comment: what do you mean by "check against". Do you want to verify that the string contains them?

Comment: As long as it finds one of the values, it's fine, so I guess OR. Is it as easy as just "/KAT_ALL|KAT_ALL|KAT_71/

Comment: Yes, verify that the string contains one of the values from the regex.

Comment: So isn't `/KAT_ALL|KAT_ALL|KAT_71/` working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it is as simple as you wrote it yourself in the comments above.
If you want to create the Regex dynamically, you can first create a string, then create a regex out of that string, and then test.
For example:

```
var expressions = ["KAT_ALL", "KAT_71", "KAT_81"];
var regexStr = expressions.join('|');
var regex = new RegExp(regexStr);
regex.test(yourString); //returns true or false
```

Comment: Thanks. One more case if you have time. A regex for ("STTYPE_YU") AND ("KAT_71" OR "KAT_81"). That should be /(STTYPE_YU)(KAT_71|KAT_81)/ right (Can't get this to work)?

Answer (score 1):

You are close with `(?=SSTYPE_YU)(?=KAT_71|KAT_81)`, use this one:

```
^(?=.*SSTYPE_YU)(?=.*(?:KAT_71|KAT_81))
```